# Unit test controller containing $state.includes()

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

How can I unit test a code inside a condition ($state.includes())

```
this.state = $state; // in constructor
...

if (this.scope.includes("myState0"))
{
  // do T0
}
else if (this.scope.includes("myState1"))
{
  // do T1
}
// .....
else if (this.scope.includes("myState14"))
{
  // do T14
}
else
{
  // do something
}
```

i tried to set this.state by doing

```
controller.state.current.name = "myState0";
```

but this.state.includes("myState0") is false in the controller. any idea ?

i also tried

```
controller.state.go('myState')
```

FYI: i found a solution but i think it's a hack
create new function

in the test, we mock state.includes() by param

```
    controller.state.current.name = 'state';
    
    spyOn(controller.state, "includes").and.callFake(function (param) {
        return controller.state.current.name === param;
    });
```